# How not to start the video playback immediately?

Tags: android

I am creating a surface holder for displaying my video and creating the mediaplayer instance as well. My question is -
How to display the first frame on the surfaceView and then provide a button for the user to click that starts the actual playback of the video?

Currently, my screen is totally black before the user presses the button that calls mediaplayerinstance.start(). I would rather have a frame there instead of nothing.

Is this possible to achieve? seekTo to the first 1 sec of the video content does not help. I don't see the frame at the 1st sec until start() is invoked.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have a solution for this. Using a background image for the surface view and removing the background before calling `mediaplayerinstance.start()` works for me.